# Modal/Partial view uk date conflict MVC5

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, bootstrap-modal

I am having a problem with jquery validation within a Modal/Partial View as it's conflicting with my main view.  The main issue is with  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") as when I add it to my main view, the main form will no longer submit (doesn't hit the controller) as the validation is rejecting UK style dates (as you can see in my code, I am using DateITA to solve this problem in my Modal and submits with no issues)

I have tried moving @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") to the partial view & the main page will now submit, but it breaks my submit for the Modal.  I have also tried naming the main view form & modal form to apply the validation to just the modal, but this hasn't helped.

Thanks

Main view

```
@model Puspers2.ViewModels.ContractViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contract";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "mainForm" }))
{

 <div class="form-group form-inline datepickerWidth">
                        <div class='input-group date mydatepicker datepickerWidth'>

                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TblContract.OrderPlacedDate, new { title = "Order Placed Date", placeholder = "dd/mm/yyyy", @class = "form-control datepickerWidth", onclick = "this.select()", id = "orderPlacedDate" })
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>

                    </div>

<div class='form-group form-inline datepickerWidth'>
                        <div class='input-group date mydatepicker datepickerWidth'>

                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TblContract.ContractStartDate, new { title = "Contract Start Date", placeholder = "dd/mm/yyyy", @class = "form-control datepickerWidth", id = "contractStartDate", onclick = "this.select()" })
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>


  <!--SAVE BUTTON-->
            <br /><br /><br /><br />
            <div class="form-group absolute">
                <hr />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg saveButtonPadding" value="save" formaction="ContractUpdate" formmethod="post" id="saveButton">Save</button>
            </div>
            <!--SAVE BUTTON-->


}


<!--div to hold the Partial view that forms the modal-->
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Partial("_ContractContributionDetails")
</div>
<!--end div to hold the Partial view that forms the modal-->


@section scripts{

   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script>

        //Modal

        $(document).on('click', '#SaveContractContribution', function () {           

            var $form = $('#modalForm')

            .validate({
                rules: {
                    TblContractContributionHistory_CommencementDeductions: {
                        dateITA: true
                    }
                }
            });

            if ($form.valid()) {

                $.ajax({

                    async: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ContractContributionHistoryAdd',
                    datatype: "json",
                    data: {
                        contractNumber: $("#contractNumber").val(),
                        commencementDeductions: $('#TblContractContributionHistory_CommencementDeductions').val(),
                        deductionsCategoryId: $('#deductionsCategory').val(),
                        numberOfContributions: $('#TblContractContributionHistory_NumberOfContributions').val(),
                        employeeContributionReference: $('#TblContractContributionHistory_EmployeeContributionReference').val(),
                        teamMember: $('#TblContractContributionHistory_TeamMemberId').val()

                    },

                    success: function (data) {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                });
            }
        });


 // >> JS snippet to handle datepicker functionality >>
        $(function () {
            $('.mydatepicker').datetimepicker({
                locale: 'en-gb',
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                showTodayButton: true,
                showClear: true,

            })
            .on('dp.hide', function () {    // on hiding data picker, record associated entryfield to allow focus to be set when built-in blur happens
                dateField = $(this).find('input');
                $("#contractStartDate,#contractEndDate,#actualTerminationDate").trigger("change")
                PickerClosing = true;
            });

            // on exit from date field, check if caused by picker closing. If Yes, set focus back in field
            $('.mydatepicker input').blur(function (e) {
                if (PickerClosing == true) {
                    PickerClosing = false;
                    dateField.focus();
                }
            });

        });
        // << JS snippet to handle datepicker functionality <<


 </script>

}
```

Partial View

```
@model Puspers2.ViewModels.ContractViewModel
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/bootbox.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/respond.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/moment.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/moment-with-locales.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js")

@{

}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ContractContributionHistoryAdd", "Home", new AjaxOptions
{ }, new { id = "modalForm" }))
{
    <div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">

            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content modalContentDeductions">

                    <h2 class="modal-header">Add Deduction</h2>

                    <div class="modal-body">     

                        <p class="dateLabels"><strong>Deductions Commenced On</strong></p>

                        <div class='form-group form-inline modalDatepickerWidth'>
                            <div class='input-group date mydatepicker modalDatepickerWidth'>

                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TblContractContributionHistory.CommencementDeductions, new { title = "Commencement Deductions", @class = "form-control inputSizeMedium" })
                                <span class="input-group-addon">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>                    

                         <div class='form-group'>

                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TblContractContributionHistory.DeductionsCategoryId, new { title = "Payment" })
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TblContractContributionHistory.DeductionsCategoryId, new SelectList(Model.TblDeductionsCategoryLOOKUP, "DeductionsCategoryId", "Category"), "Select Option", new { @class = "form-control inputSizeMedium", @id="deductionsCategory"})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TblContractContributionHistory.DeductionsCategoryId)
                        </div> 

                        <div class="form-group">

                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TblContractContributionHistory.EmployeeContributionReference, new { title = "Monthly Cost To Employee" })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TblContractContributionHistory.EmployeeContributionReference, new { title = "Monthly Cost To Employee", @class = "form-control inputSizeMedium" })

                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">

                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TblContractContributionHistory.NumberOfContributions, new { title = "" })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TblContractContributionHistory.NumberOfContributions, new { title = "", @class = "form-control inputSizeMedium" })

                        </div>

                        <div class='form-group'>

                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TblContractContributionHistory.TeamMemberId, new { title = "" })
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TblContractContributionHistory.TeamMemberId, new SelectList(Model.TblTeamMembersLOOKUP, "TeamMemberId", "TeamMemberName"), "Select Option", new { @class = "form-control inputSizeMedium" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TblContractContributionHistory.TeamMemberId)
                        </div>  

                        <br />

                        <div>
                            <button id="SaveContractContribution" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="save" formmethod="post">Save</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}


@section scripts
{

<script>    

    $(function () {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#modalForm');
    });

    $(function () {
        $('.mydatepicker').datetimepicker({
            locale: 'en-gb',
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            showTodayButton: true,
            showClear: true,

        })
        .on('dp.hide', function () {    // on hiding data picker, record associated entryfield to allow focus to be set when built-in blur happens
            dateField = $(this).find('input');
            $("#contractStartDate,#contractEndDate,#actualTerminationDate").trigger("change")
            PickerClosing = true;
        });

        // on exit from date field, check if caused by picker closing. If Yes, set focus back in field
        $('.mydatepicker input').blur(function (e) {
            if (PickerClosing == true) {
                PickerClosing = false;
                dateField.focus();
            }
        });
    })

  </script>
}
```

DateITA

```
$.validator.addMethod( "dateITA", function( value, element ) {
    var check = false,
        re = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/,
        adata, gg, mm, aaaa, xdata;
    if ( re.test( value ) ) {
        adata = value.split( "/" );
        gg = parseInt( adata[ 0 ], 10 );
        mm = parseInt( adata[ 1 ], 10 );
        aaaa = parseInt( adata[ 2 ], 10 );
        xdata = new Date( Date.UTC( aaaa, mm - 1, gg, 12, 0, 0, 0 ) );
        if ( ( xdata.getUTCFullYear() === aaaa ) && ( xdata.getUTCMonth() === mm - 1 ) && ( xdata.getUTCDate() === gg ) ) {
            check = true;
        } else {
            check = false;
        }
    } else {
        check = false;
    }
    return this.optional( element ) || check;
}, $.validator.messages.date );
```